# WCF JSON returned as null

Tags: json, wcf, windows-phone-8

Following this [tutorial](http://debugmode.net/2011/12/22/how-to-consume-wcf-rest-service-with-json-in-windows-phone-7/): I have created a WP8 Mobile Application and trying to call my WCF web service. When calling the WCF service in the browser, I can see the JSON returned with no problems at all. However, when I call the WCF service in my mobile application, I don't get anything back. I have no clue where I am going wrong.

This is the code that call the WCF:

```
string ServiceUri = "urlgoeshere";
WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
proxy.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(proxy_DownloadStringCompleted);
proxy.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(ServiceUri));
```

And the event handler:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result));
DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<SightingType>));
var result = obj.ReadObject(stream) as List<SightingType>;
```

What am I doing wrong? I've obviously changed the ServiceUri to "urlgoeshere" but rest assured, the actual URL works perfectly, 100% A-OK when I run it in my browser. When running it in this mobile app however, it doesn't work. Can anyone see the obvious problem?

**Update**

If I do:
`var result = obj.ReadObject(stream);`, and if I step into `stream`, I can see a:

```
ReadTimeout = 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Comment: Is the value of `e.Result` a properly formed JSON array (since you're deserializing into a `List<...>`)?

Comment: where is your `JSON` response and how your `SightingType` class looks loke?